# I made jquery slider but can not change the images served by google

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, slider, slideshow

I made jquery slider but can not change the images served by google. I just want to change the images but have no idea how to do this. I really need help as I am an amateur but working hard to learn. My site is "bayareaportrait.com" and I do not like one of the images in the slideshow and would like to add more images but it seems like I'm stuck with this slideshow forever. I'm sorry to be so ignorant but I built my site in Dreamweaver and have hand coded a couple of things but I'm old and I just don't understand what is going on here. Thank you for any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the big image slider on the home page?

I'm assuming you are using Jquery.cycle.all.js at http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ which is in your JavaScript source files.

from reading: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/begin.html

To add an image to the slider you need to copy one of the `<img>` tag lines and change the URL to the new image.

```
<div class="pics"> 
    <img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
</div>
```

In this example I would copy the fourth line and paste it below then change the text in the     src="TEXT" attribute to the new images url.

like so:

```
<div class="pics"> 
    <img src="images/beach1.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/beach2.jpg" width="200" height="200" /> 
    <img src="images/beach3.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
    <img src="images/beach4.jpg" width="200" height="200" />
</div>
```

To delete an image its a simple case of removing teh corresponding `<img>` trag line.